# JSON object "undefined" error in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am uploading a file using PHP and want to return the file name and the file status to javascript. In PHP I create the json object by:

```
$value = array('result' => $result, 'fileName' => $_FILES['myfile']['name']);   
print_r ($value);
$uploadData = json_encode($value);
```

This creates the json object. I then send it to a function in javascript and recieve it as a variable called fileStatus.

```
alert (fileStatus);
```

It displays

```
{"result":"success","fileName":"cake"}
```

which should be good. But when I try and do

```
fileStatus.result or fileStatus.fileName
```

I get an error saying that they are undefined. Please help I'm really stuck on this. Thanks.

Comment: `fileStatus` is probably the JSON string containing `{"result":"success","fileName":"cake"}`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `fileStatus`?

Comment: Guess you got some scoping problems, can you show the actual code?

Comment: Are you correctly setting the document type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file/267554#267554

Comment: Gumbo is correct. fileStatus is the JSON string.

function stopUpload(fileStatus){

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fileStatus` is just a string at this point, so it does not have properties such as `result` and `fileName`. You need to parse the string into a JSON object, using a method such as Firefox's native [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) or jQuery's [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

**Example:**

```
var fileStatusObj = jQuery.parseJSON(fileStatus);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the alert displays `{"result":"success","fileName":"cake"}` then you probably still have to turn the string into a JSON object. Depending on the browsers you are developing for you can use the [native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json) support or the [JSON.org](http://json.org) implementation to turn your string into an object. From there on it should work as expected.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the evil `eval` function.

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't want to. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the variable, do not put quotes around it.  Just set the variable like this:

```
var fileStatus = <?php echo $uploadData; ?>;
```

or:

```
var fileStatus = <?=$uploadData?>;
```

*Do not* do this:

```
var fileStatus = '<?php echo $uploadData; ?>';
```